# Regex function to clean salutations

Tags: sql-server

How do I write a regex function for cleaning Salutations in SQL Server?

I have a salutations column and it contains names like 
Mr. Mainland
Mrs. Frankhouse
Miss. Ellsberg  etc

but there are salutations, which only have 
Mr. 
Miss. 
Mrs. 
and then nothing else. 
How do I write a regex function that takes exactly takes those ones out and replaces them with the word: Hi, but leave any Mr., Miss., Mr. & Mrs., Mrs. -if there is an actual name to follow ?

What I have is when Salutation has less than 1 character or more than 15, then the Salutation code needs to be 'Hi' How do I write now : or when Salutation in ( Mr. , Miss. , Mrs. ) and then nothing behind  `then ' Hi'`

```
select 
case when LEN(c.[salutation])  <= 1 OR LEN(c.[salutation]) > 15 OR c.[salutation] IS NULL then ' Hi' ELSE (concat ( ' ',[salutation])) end as [Salutation ]
 from tab AS  c
```

Comment: can you please share sample data and expected output?

Comment: SQL Server does not support Regex natively. If you need to use Regex you'll need to look into CLR functions; I'm sure a quick search will lead to a few.

Comment: it looks like:                                                                                                                  Mr. Mainland    needs to be       Mr. Mainland                                                                                                              Mr.                   needs to be                Hi                                                                                           
Mrs                needs to be                  Hi

Comment: Can I do something like:                                                                                                       select
c.[salutation]
 , case when  LEN(c.[salutation]) > 15 OR c.[salutation] IS NULL or c.[salutation] in (MR. , ' ' , Mrs., ' ', Miss, ' ' ) then ' Hi' ELSE (concat ( ' ',[salutation])) end as [Salutation ]
 from tab AS  c

Comment: The ask here is not very clear. Can you please revise the question?

Comment: if salutation has has 1 or less characters or equal to or more than 15 characters then replace field in  salutation with 'Hi'                                                               if Salutation is only Mr. / Mrs / mrs./ Miss /  mrs & miss (as the only salutation- so has no name after mr etc) then replace field in  salutation with 'Hi'

Comment: What results are you getting when you run your case statement?

Comment: this part:  c.[salutation] in (MR. , ' ' , Mrs., ' ', Miss, ' ' ) does not work, the rest does  How do I write : if salutation in  (MR. ? , Mrs. ? Miss ) - because I only want to address recons that don't have a proper salutation

Comment: no, because that will take out all salutation in which I we have 'MR.','Mrs.','Miss' - if a salutation has e.f Mr. Mainfield - then I want to leave it, if a salutation has just Mr. then it needs to be 'Hi' as salutation

Comment: Mr, Mrs, Dr, Honorable, Senator etc are prefixes.   Jr, Sr, MD, Phd, DDS, Esq are suffixes.   A salutation is a greeting like Dears Sirs.

Answer (score 0):

OK found the solution:

```
select
c.[salutation]
 , case when  LEN(c.[salutation]) > 15 OR c.[salutation] IS NULL or (LEFT( c.[salutation],5) in ( 'Mr', 'Mrs', 'Miss', 'Mr &' , 'Mrs &' )) then ' Hi' ELSE (concat ( ' ',[salutation])) end as [Salutation ]
 from [tab] AS c
```